# Mongodb load collection by ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, meanjs

Probably something very simple here. 
I have 2 mongoDb collections, one (users) with an objectId and the other (listings) which has the userId.

I want to get the documents in the listing collection by searching the objectId (currentUser._id).

How would i do this?

Component for page i want to display the listings on:

```
export class ManageComponent implements OnInit {
    listing : Listing;
    listings: Listing[] = [];
currentUser: User;

constructor(
    private listingService: ListingService,
    private userService: UserService) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
     }  

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllListings();
} 

private loadAllListings() {
    this.listingService.getAll().subscribe(listings => { this.listings = listings; });
}


private loadById(userId: string) {
    this.listingService.getById(userId).subscribe(listings => { this.listings = listings});
    }
}
```

I have a listing service that is used to for the CRUD operations (some omitted)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Listing } from '../_models/index';

@Injectable()
export class ListingService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getAll() {
    return this.http.get('/listings').map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

getById(_id: string) {
    return this.http.get('/listings/' + _id).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

getByUserId(userId: string) {
    return this.http.get('/listings/' + userId).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

create(listing: Listing) {
    return this.http.post('/listings/add', listing);
}
```

Server side listing controller which uses the server side service (see below):

```
function getRelevant(req, res) {
listingService.getByUserId(req.listing.sub)
    .then(function (listing) {
        if (listing) {
            res.send(listing);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
```

Server side listing service:

```
function getByUserId(userId) {
var deferred = Q.defer();

db.listings.findById(userId, function (err, listing) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

    if (listing) {
        // return listing 
        deferred.resolve(listing);
    } else {
        // listing not found
        deferred.resolve();
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, so I won't be providing this as an answer, but are you looking for something like (pseudocode) `var your_user = db.users.findOne({_id: some_user_id}); var user_listings = db.listings.find({user_id: your_user._id});`?

Comment: This is "front end" code and nothing to do with the database. There are plenty of tutorials out there with basic CRUD operations. I would suggest you start with the core documentation on [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) and then look for ones using the specific driver implemtation after. Stack Overflow is not a service for someone to "write your code for you". If you have back end code and trouble with one part, then show your effort and someone can point you in the right direction. Generally asking for "end to end" as essentially a "tutorial" is far too broad.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I have backend code also but essentially what i wanted to do, as i have the _id of the currently logged in user already, i wanted to return documents in the listings collection that use this _id as a reference.

Comment: Essentially "your question is too broad". If you have back end code then this should be the **only** code in the question and you can ask about the "specific" part you don't understand. I cannot be more clear on this. Not going to give an "end to end tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

db.listings.aggregate([ $lookup:{
          from: "users",
          localField: "currentUser._id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "result"
        }
   }
]).findOne({
user_id: id you want to search
})

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's function `findById()` will find the current model's documents by Id on which the function is operated (`db.listings.findById()` will find All Listings by Listing Id).

That said, if you want to `find` by other criteria that is in your model (`listing`). You need to do `find({query})`.

Specifically in your case, you'll need to:

```
const query = {userId: userIdThatIsPassedIn};
db.listings.find(query).exec(callback);
```